# In Bash Script how do I transverse into a directory inside my current directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory

So my current code is like so: 
scan.h

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    byte=$(stat -c%s "$line");
    echo "$line : $byte";
done< <(ls *.$1)
```

In UNIX once I run my code it would preform like this:

```
./scan.sh cpp
arraysum.cpp : 359
countLines.cpp : 1199
createtext.cpp : 240
multiproc1.cpp : 196
myWc.cpp : 1230
test.cpp : 193
```

This is expected as it shows all the .cpp files in my current directory followed by their byte count. However, I also want to locate the other files in the folders of my directory, but I can't seem to figure out how to transverse into them.

Sidenote: Also just out of curiosity, is their anyway I could sort out my print statements based on byte size?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would use `find` to search directories recursively e.g.

```
find . -name '*.cpp'
```

If you have GNU `find`, you can print out the filename and size in bytes directly, avoiding a call to `stat`

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -printf '%f:%s\n'
```

If you don't mind reversing the order, you can output the results in a way that's unambiguously sortable - for example to sort on size numerically from high to low

```
find ../src -name '*.cpp' -printf '%s:%f\n' | sort -t: -rn
```

You can always swap the fields after sorting e.g. with Awk - that also allows you to select just the top 5 results for example:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -printf '%s:%f\n' | sort -t: -rn | awk -F: 'NR==6 {exit} {print $2 " : " $1}'
```

Finally, if you want to make it safe for any "legal" filenames (including those with newlines), null terminate everything

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -printf '%s:%f\0' | sort -t: -zrn | awk -vRS='\0' -F: 'NR==6 {exit} {print $2 " : " $1}'
```

Comment: Hm thanks I never really though of that, I'm still rather new to bash. But if it's not to much trouble to keep asking, say if I only wanted to print out 5 files, like the top 5 with the first being the most bytes (including all the stuff above which you mentioned).

Comment: @LiWang please see updated answer

Comment: `sort` has the ability to sort using any field order -- look up its `-k` and `-t` options in the manual; no need to swap it back and forth.

Comment: @mosvy the point is that there is no field delimiter that can be guaranteed not to also be present in the filename and (AFAIK) no way to tell `sort` to sort on the *last* of a potentially arbitrary number of fields

Comment: Hey sorry to bug you again but so I was wondering if their was any alternative way to take requests from the command-line input. So say I want to do "scan.h cpp 8" in the UNIX terminal, where "cpp" is the first command line for what type I want followed by "8" being the amount I want to output being the top eight. Normally I could use $1 and $2 but those are being used already so I'm not sure how this is gonna work. (Also a bit of a side note but is their always a way to print out all the files but include their pathname? Eg: ./a/b/file.cpp )

Comment: @LiWang you can put the `find` command in a script and pass positional parameters just like you did before e.g. `find . -name "*.$1"  . . . `. For the Awk command, use `-v num=$2` to pass the second positional parameter via a variable called `num` and then change `NR==6` to `NR-1==num`. The `$1` and `$2` *inside* the Awk expression are protected from expansion by the quoting, and will **not** be mistaken for shell positional parameters. Finally, to get the full pathname, change `%f` in the `-printf` format to `%p`.

Comment: For some weird reason, while the %p works fine, when I swap out the *.cpp with say a $1 and upon running the code I get no output.  So say if I type in " scan.h cpp 50 " I get blank output. My code is as follows: [ find . -name  ' .$1' -printf '%s:%p\0' | sort -t: -zrn | awk -vRS='\0' -v num=%2 -F: 'NR-1==num {exit} {print $2 " : " $1} {total = total + $1} END {print total} ]

Comment: @LiWang you need to use *double quotes* not *single quotes* in order for the positional parameter to be expanded: `-name "*.$1"`

Comment: Ah ok, yea my mistake.